# Can I restrict the types of a subclass in Python?

Tags: python, oop, type-hinting, static-typing, pyright

Let's say I want to do define wrapper classes on sets and lists that add some useful methods, like this:

```
from abc import ABC

class AbstractGizmo(ABC):

    def bloviate(self):
        print(f"Let me tell you more about my {len(self)} elements")

class ListGizmo(list, AbstractGizmo):
    pass    

class SetGizmo(set, AbstractGizmo):
    pass
```

Now I can call:

```
>>> ListGizmo([1, 2, 3]).bloviate()
>>> SetGizmo({1, 2, 3}).bloviate()
```

But I also want to have `bloviate()` available on its own as a utility method:

```
from typing import Union, Set, List

def bloviate(collection: Union[Set, List]):
    print(f"Let me tell you more about my {len(collection)} elements")


class AbstractGizmo(ABC):

    def bloviate(self):
        return bloviate(self)
```

So I can also do:

```
>>> bloviate([1, 2, 3])
>>> bloviate({1, 2, 3})
```

Since subclass `ListGizmo` *is* a list, and subclass `SetGizmo` *is* a set, this setup actually works fine in practice. But static type checkers (like pyright) don't know that, so they (correctly) show an error here:

```
class AbstractGizmo(ABC):

    def bloviate(self):
        return bloviate(self)  # Error: Type 'AbstractGizmo' cannot be assigned
                               # to type 'Set[Unknown] | List[Unknown]'
```

Is there some way I can indicate to Python / pyright that, essentially, "all instances of `AbstractGizmo` are guaranteed to be in `Union[Set, List]`"? This syntax escapes me.

(Note that of course in this simple example I can just define `bloviate()` on each subclass to avoid the problem. In reality I have more methods and more wrapper subclasses, so I get a combinatorial explosion if I can't abstract them to `AbstractGizmo`.)

Answer (score 0):

To properly [type mixin classes](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#mixin-classes), annotate the `self` parameter as a [`Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) matching the functionality of the desired base types:

```py
from typing import Protocol
from abc import ABC

class HasLength(Protocol):  # or just `typing.Sized` in this case
    def __len__(self) -> int: ...

def bloviate(collection: HasLength):
    print(f"Let me tell you more about my {len(collection)} elements")

class AbstractGizmo(ABC):
    def bloviate(self: HasLength):
        return bloviate(self)

class ListGizmo(list, AbstractGizmo):
    pass

ListGizmo().bloviate()  # this is fine
```

Note that the mixin can still be combined with other types *without* raising a static type error. However, using the respective method triggers an error both furing runtime and static type checking.

```py
class IntGizmo(int, AbstractGizmo):
    pass

IntGizmo().bloviate() # error: Invalid self argument "IntGizmo" to attribute function "bloviate" with type "Callable[[HasLength], Any]"
```